# Db2 error on datetime

Tags: database, db2

I am getting an error when trying to issue an insert statement.  The error code is `181` and state is `22007`.  From what I can tell this error has to do with a string representation of a date time is not valid.

My date is `01/04/2014 12:00 AM`
Any ideas? I am using DB2 version 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, but your date format looks a lot like a `.NET` date type. If you are using the IBM.Data.DB2 interface in `.NET`, then when you add a parameter to your query for your date (and if you're not using parameters, you [should be](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2006/07/21/10728.aspx)), you can specify the data type.

Here is some example code in VB.NET:

```vb
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO test.table (DATE_FIELD, TIMESTAMP_FIELD) VALUES (@dateField, @timestampField)"

Using conn = GetDb2Connection()
    Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = sql

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateField", DB2Type.Date).Value = New DateTime(2014, 3, 6)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@timestampField", DB2Type.Timestamp).Value = New DateTime(2014, 3, 6, 8, 5, 0)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the database is not configured with the same locale you are giving the date. In this case, you should use a formatter, giving the structure of the date you are providing.

```
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(
   '31/12/1999 12:00 AM',
   'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM')
```

- timestamp_format http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html
- varchar_format http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html

Comment: ...and this is why ISO formatting for data you control.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the column was specified as a DATE.  Prior to DB2 and New Function Mode, DB2 was a little more forgiving and would strip off the time portion of the date for you during insert.  Now it is sticking to its guns :) and will throw the 181 error.  So long story short, the fix is a code change to remove the time from the date since we do not use it within our application.  I guess another solution if you did need the time, would be to alter the column data type.